# Does groupExchanges() method still exist in apache Camel as part of the AggregationDefinition?

Tags: apache-camel, integration-patterns

Is there a replacement for the groupExchanges() method;
which, according to the [latest documentation](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/eips/aggregate-eip.html#_using_groupedexchanges), should be possible however, I am unable to compile the code as the method seems to have vanished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method is deprecated since Apache Camel 2.15.x and removed since 2.18.x. You are supposed to use [`GroupedExchangeAggregationStrategy`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.apache.camel/camel-core/2.25.2/org/apache/camel/processor/aggregate/GroupedExchangeAggregationStrategy.html) instead.

```
.aggregate(new GroupedExchangeAggregationStrategy()) // Or AggregationStrategies.groupedExchange()
```

I have [fixed](https://github.com/apache/camel/commit/e760248069556c81d57adbd7d91cdadd2d036be7) documentation, on the website it will be deployed soon.